# How to curl and unzip to a certain directory?

Tags: io-redirection, curl, zip

How to curl and unzip to a certain directory?

you curl a file to stdout then unzip to some dir.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`unzip` (version 6.00) can not extract files read from standard input (this is mentioned in the `unzip` manual, in the "BUGS" section), so the file will need to be saved locally before extraction:

```
curl -o myfile.zip "some URL"
unzip myfile.zip -d "some directory"
rm -f myfile.zip
```

where `some directory` is the directory into which you'd like to extract the archive.

Comment: But `jar` can...

Comment: As @StephenKitt said: `curl $zip_file_url | jar xv`